# How do I populate a combobox from an array in PHP?

Tags: php, html, arrays, combobox

I want to have an simple array in php and a combobox in html.

```
<?php
// Here is my array:
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code in php page :

```
<?php
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
$smarty->assign('cars', $cars);
?>
```

Smarty code for HTML page(Template page):

```
<select name="car">
  {foreach from=$cars item=car}
    <option value="{$car}">{$car}</option>
  {/foreach}
</select>
```

Comment: well,this code shows into my combobox $car,not kind of cars. :(

Comment: This code is for smarty, Have you included smarty ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==="POST") {
    if (isset($_POST['car'])) {
        if (in_array($_POST['car'],$cars)) {
            echo "You selected ".$_POST['car']."!";
            exit;
        }
    }
}

?>
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <select name="car">
        <?php
        foreach ($cars as $car) {
            echo '<option value="'.$car.'">'.$car.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Select">
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work.In my html page it just shows the empty combobox and doesn't read from array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "<select name='cars'>";
foreach($cars as $car)
{
   echo "<option value='".$car."'>".$car."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: OK,i wana to show php array into smarty template or html page.is it work?my array is in php page and my combobox is in html page or smarty template.

Comment: No problem you can use php script on your page